# How to make the updated_by field display the user's full name in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

I just recently started using Django. Please help me figure it out. I have a database that stores various information about network devices. On the site, this information is displayed in a table. I want the updated_by field to display the full name of the user who created this table or who last modified it. All users are registered in Django, there are fields: first name, last name. I want these two fields to be displayed together in the table in the updated_by field. For example, at the end of the table on the site it was written: Updated by an employee: Ivanov Ivan.

I tried to do this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Updated by an employee', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='Employee deleted')
```

But I am getting an error

```
OperationalError at /admin/mainapp/device/1/change/
no such column: device.updated_by_id
```

My code models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Device(models.Model):
        device_vendor = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Vendor')
        device_model = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Model')
        device_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Hostname')
        device_serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Serial number')
        device_description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Description')
        project = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Project')
        updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User.get_full_name(), verbose_name='Updated by', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='None')
        # updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='Updated by')
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Updated at')
        rack_id = models.ForeignKey(Rack, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Rack')
```

Comment: Use these commands :`python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Performed migrations, does not help

Comment: your requirements and Error are kinda different. while using `updated_by_id` shouldn't give you an error if you have migrated already. Can you share Code where you want to fetch the first and last name

Comment: The first and last name are stored in the Django admin panel, which is created automatically, as I understand it, when creating a project

Comment: where you want to display first and last name? in admin panel? and also take a look at [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model) first and last name are field of `auth_user` Table.

Comment: I want to display the first and last name in my table of network devices on the site. I have a table in which information: manufacturer, device name, inventory number, dimensions, etc. And at the very end of this table, I need to display information about who created or modified this table among Django users.

Comment: Something like this I need - updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User.get_full_name, verbose_name='Updated by an employee', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='Employee deleted')

Comment: you can't perform this `updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User.get_full_name(), verbose_name='Updated by', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='None')`
You can display fullname as I mentioned in my answer in your `UI/website` and `admin panel` not directly in your database. Another option you can 2 have fields, one as a Foreign key and the other to store full name. which at the end you have to use query to fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch User details which used as a Foreign key to another table.
assuming model name `Foo`:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Concat
from django.db.models import Value


data = Foo.objects.filter().annotate(full_name=Concat("updated_by__first_name", Value(" "), "updated_by__last_name"))
```

This will return User's full name.

**UPDATE**

you can override your save method to get full name of that user and store it in another field:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Device(models.Model):
        device_vendor = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Vendor')
        device_model = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Model')
        device_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Hostname')
        device_serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Serial number')
        device_description = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name='Description')
        project = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, verbose_name='Project')
        updated_by = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Updated by', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default='None')
        updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Updated at')
        rack_id = models.ForeignKey(Rack, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Rack')
        user_full_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True,blank=True) # add this and do migrate

        def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.user_full_name = self.updated_by.first_name + ' ' + self.updated_by.last_name
            super(Device, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand where to insert this, I tried it in models.py, but when migrating it says: It is impossible to change a nullable field 'updated_by' on building to non-nullable without providing a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.

Comment: updated answer. your model will look like this. if possible Delete migrations File which are generate in your `django-app`. dont delete `__init__.py`. delete rest files and do migrations again.

Comment: Migrations were successful, but gives an error when going to the site:
OperationalError at /admin/mainapp/device/
no such column: device.updated_by_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/mainapp/device/
Django Version: 4.2
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
no such column: device.updated_by_id
Exception Location: C:\PycharmProjects\code\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 328, in execute
Raised during: django.contrib.admin.options.changelist_view

Comment: please update post with new code.

Comment: Above Code had an Error earlier. Model field is `updated_by` and i used `user_by` in `save` method.Fixed

Comment: It doesn’t work, okay, I’ll just have to leave this field required and fill it in manually, but thanks for the help